# Java Stopwatch method

Tags: java, timer, stopwatch

I have this script to run through a bunch of queries and writes the results and runtime to a txt file.

This works ok for small data sets, but for larger longer queries I get a lot of

**This stopwatch is already running.** messages.

Here is the relevant code

```
Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();


    for(String query: qrys) {
        try {
            timer.start();
            resQryES = methodforQrys(url, query);   // query result is saved in the iterable Map resQryES
            timer.stop();

            out.println("Query: " + query);
            out.println("Query execution time: " + timer);
            out.println("Query Results : " + resQryES);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }


    out.close();
```

I'm thinking perhaps its because the queries are executing in parallel , 
so a stopwatch is still running - so it works with smaller datasets as queries are so fast it doesn't run any in parallel.

Should I try using a different loop type where I use indexes, and create 
a matching map/array of timer values so none get mixed up ...

Comment: Does `methodforQrys` start up a new thread?

Comment: Have you tried putting `Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes - that fixed it thanks !  , the reason I didn't try before as I believed I allready had - but I did it before with `Stopwatch.createStarted();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned is the comments as well. Just put this line of code inside your for loop so that it will reset for every iteration.

`Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();`

Your code should look like this:

```
for(String query: qrys) {
    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
    try {
        timer.start();
        resQryES = methodforQrys(url, query);   // query result is saved in the iterable Map resQryES
        timer.stop();

        out.println("Query: " + query);
        out.println("Query execution time: " + timer);
        out.println("Query Results : " + resQryES);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}


out.close();
```

Comment: yep, thanks a lot all ... btw, just on a side note, if I wanna debug or view each thread created here, whats the best way ?

Comment: @Yozzer There are no separate threads created here particularly. For debugging, you can run your code with a debugger, exacts steps of which will depend on the IDE you are using.